# How to preserve customization while upgrading to a new version of nopCommerce?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce, affiliate

I'm working on NopCommerce 2.60 and  I have extended Affiliate Module in NopCommerce 2.6 by adding two new fields like "WebsiteURL" and "Picture Upload".

For that I have made changes in `Affiliate Services`, `Affiliate Controller`, `Affiliate.cs`, `Affiliate Map`, `Affiliate Model` files. Now If I want to integrate these changes in upcoming versions of NopCommerce.

So What is better way to make changes in NopCommerce code and easily integrate in upcoming versions of NopCommerce?

Comment: Check this question. It is for more recent version of nop commerce. But problem is same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734541/upgrade-nopcommerce-2-8-to-3-10

Answer (score 0):

There is no any way in nopcommerce  to upgrade custom functionality in higher version. instead of that i would suggest right you function independent to nop means write separate classes for all Affiliate  functionality, copy it in next version as you see in nopcommerce2.65 they have change some service, properties name.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently looked into this since our company wanted to make sure nopCommerce could be upgraded at later dates if needed. The best solution we found was to make our modifications into plugins so that we could refrain from modifying the core as much as possible. Like Shivkumar said, it's not really possible to make nopCommerce [upgrade proof](http://blog.csharpwebdeveloper.com/2011/09/27/cheat-sheet-for-effectively-extending-nopcommerce/).

Hope this helps.