# How to extend existing pages, such as Customer or Shopping Cart, through plugins?

Tags: nopcommerce

I've read everywhere that it's better to write new plugin than touch the core code. The problem is that I've not been able to find documentation where it's explain clearly how to modify pages from the plugin.

The way I understood it, to display partial pages from the plugin, one needs to tells where to display them by return using this method:

```
public IList<string> GetWidgetZones()
```

But if you return more than one zone, the widget will be displayed in multiple zones. What if I want to display bit of information on different zones?

To start off, I'd like to extend the the Customer page. The menu on that page has  7 items: customer info, addresses, orders, downloadable products, back in stock subscriptions, reward points, and change password.

I'd like to add 2 more items: personal info and connections. When personal info is clicked, the customer will able to add extra info, such as his/her photo. When the connections is clicked, user would be able to see what other have been doing.

Can someone point me to the documentation that explain how one can extend existing pages, such as Customer and Shopping Cart, without touching the core code.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I have read people saying do modifications as much as using plugin. But in practical i do find modifying core logic is one good way to find elegant and less complex way of customizing to our need.

Because, plugins only provides up to a certain limit of modification. In your case, widgets can be extended. But i don't think customer detail page can be extended using plugins. based on your requirements, you may need to add additional columns/attributes for customers. Yes, you can add/remove columns while installing/removing plugins. But in practical, any user in admin can uninstall a pluign. Think if this happens in PROD. Also you have not elaborated about connections.

I have done 250+ custom modifications (to suite our need) on core nopcommerce for my organization over the period of 2.5years. I started with nop 2.65 then moved to 2.80 and then moved to 3.20. Its bit complex to upgrade nop commerce versions on top of our custom modifications. But i can be done, if you are organized from day one.

Here are few rules i follow,

1. Keep a detailed custom modification list in excel.
2. Always update code in such as way that new feature can be managed from admin. Example: if you add a new menu in the header, just make sure it can be shown/hidden under admin settings. And this helps to contribute back to nop commerce if possible.
3. Use a good database Diff tool.
4. Use version control.

So when a new version of nop is released, i quickly compare my excel with release notes. for migration details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734541/upgrade-nopcommerce-2-8-to-3-10)